# App is crashing when I call defaultRealm

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence, cocoapods, realm

I am trying to remove every instance of an RLMObject subclass and whenever I call [Realm defaultRealm] my app crashes. Here is what I keep getting in the console. I am using cocoapods, version 0.93.2

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't persist property 'Id' with incompatible type. Add to ignoredPropertyNames: method to ignore.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b15c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067aebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   business_sect                       0x000000010206251b -[RLMProperty initWithName:indexed:property:] + 571
3   business_sect                       0x00000001020511c1 +[RLMObjectSchema propertiesForClass:isSwift:] + 1457
4   business_sect                       0x000000010204fa5c +[RLMObjectSchema schemaForObjectClass:] + 812
5   business_sect                       0x00000001020c4d06 +[RLMSchema initialize] + 1862
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067af4d6 _class_initialize + 648
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067b86e1 lookUpImpOrForward + 351
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001067c50d3 objc_msgSend + 211
9   business_sect                       0x00000001020aa34d +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:key:readOnly:inMemory:dynamic:schema:error:] + 4765
10  business_sect                       0x00000001020a8d78 +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:] + 152
11  business_sect                       0x00000001020a8bdf +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] + 111
12  business_sect                       0x0000000101f386ff __40-[CGCUserManager signInUser:completion:]_block_invoke + 879
13  business_sect                       0x0000000101fd39d8 __64-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke46 + 40
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107095186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001070b4614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010709ca1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a7d1f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a3edcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a3e366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107d63a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x0000000104e6d8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
22  business_sect                       0x0000000101f6927f main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001070e8145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDIT: I am also testing on the iphone6 simulator

Here is the RLMObject subclass:

```
#import "RLMObject.h"

@interface CGCUser : RLMObject
@property NSString *EmailAddress;
@property BOOL IsActive;

@end
```

And a second object

```
@interface CGCCardInfo : RLMObject
@property NSInteger *Id;
@property NSString *nickName;
@property NSString *token;
@property NSString *displayNumber;
@property BOOL *isDefault;
@property NSString *cardType;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(CGCCardInfo)
```

Comment: Can you please share your `RLMObject` subclass definitions?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is the line `@property BOOL *isDefault;`

If you change that to `@property BOOL isDefault;` it should do exactly what you want!

Comment: yup, I noticed it after my edit lol The same applies to the `NSInteger *Id`

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me.

`@property NSInteger *Id` is the problematic field over here. You use a pointer to `NSInteger` instead of `NSInteger` itself.

The solution is to replace it with a direct reference: `@property NSInteger Id`